# "Study in" or "study on"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I'm reading this journal article and I keep seeing "in a study *in* malaria patients..." I think it should be "study on" or even "study among".

There's also "In a study of adult men *in* participants with whooping cough..."

What do you think?

Comment: What is the journal?  I would say "...in a study of malaria patients..."  and "In a study of adult men with whooping cough..:  It sounds like non-native authors.

Comment: Yes, they’re non-native speakers. It's not published yet and I don't know the journal it's meant for.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "study of malaria patients" is correct and that "study in malaria patients" is incorrect.  You could also say "in a study about" such as "in a study about malaria patients  or  "in a study about elephants ..." or "in a study about the causes of violent street crimes"

Answer (score 1):

I would use the phrase "study of" as in:

> In a study *of* malaria patients...

"Study in" implies either the location or the broad topic (as in "The study in the building was..." or "I study in the field of..."), not the specific topic as mentioned.

Regarding "In a study of adult men in participants with whooping cough...", I would delete the word "in" and replace "men" with "male" or delete "in participants" entirely.

Comment: Yes, it should have been male, but ULSAM is the name of a fairly well-known study in the medical community.  Here is the actual sentence:
"In the Uppsala Longitudinal Study of Adult Men (ULSAM), in participants with XYZ, ABC loosely correlated with clamp data (x=-1.76), and a supervised clinical test like the MNO showed a stronger correlation with clamp data than XYZ."